# jquery not working for multiple but same class

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have this jquery for my mobile menu, to change the class on click

```
jQuery("#slide-out-open").click(function() {
    if( jQuery( this ).hasClass( "slide-out-open" ) ) {
        jQuery('#wrapper').css({overflow:"hidden"});
        jQuery("body").addClass( 'js-nav' );
        jQuery( this ).removeClass('slide-out-open').addClass('slide-out-close');
        return false;
    }
    else if( jQuery( this ).hasClass( "slide-out-close" ) ) {
        jQuery('#wrapper').css({overflow:"auto"});
        jQuery("body").removeClass( 'js-nav' );
        jQuery( this ).removeClass('slide-out-close').addClass('slide-out-open');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Now I want to add the same button inside a left pop up menu.
I added the same php for the menu, the html is okay, but when I click the first button and it change its class, my new button didn't change the class.

So the jquery only works one time, on first class it finds. How can I change it to change both classes?

Thanks

Comment: I think your both button have slide-out-open id first time?

Comment: yes it has, but after this jquery works i will give it spesific css. edit: dang, you're right, 2 ids, i should've notice this. will try to change 2nd id, let's see what happen

Comment: just convert it in class for check once and see it works or not. because when you hit a button base on his id all thing changes like class and css but id remain same that's why it's not working for another one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`jQuery("#slide-out-open")`  this binds to an `id` html attribute, which per the spec, you can only have one element bound to a specific id.

I would suggest changing this to a class which can be selected multiple times.

side-note: using `.click` is deprecated, and will only bind to elements that were present on the page when the js is loaded.

I would suggest using `.on( 'click', function() {})` this will allow for dynamic bindings, and is the current supported method.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh and lucky7id
hi, your advice work :D
i change the jquery to jQuery(".my-slide").on( 'click', function() {}). that means i'm adding new class instead changing my id, too much work on css. and changing this part jQuery( this ) to jQuery( ".my-slide" ) so the jquery will work on all class simultaneously rather than on the clicked button. thanks awesome!

Comment: if both advice work then at-least you can vote both.

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear what exactly you mean. But first of all, two buttons shouldnt have the same ID, because IDs are supposed to be specific identifiers. Maybe that even is the problem here. (should be rather a comment, but i cant comment..)

Comment: yeah, didn't notice that i have 2 id's and also just notice jQuery( this ) only works on the clicked button. thanks